# Eclipse CDT doesn't parse the console output

Tags: error-handling, eclipse-cdt

I'm using a batch file to build my project in Eclipse (I'm using the C51 compiler from Keil). The output is correctly displayed in the Eclipse Console view, but none of the error parsers seem to do absolutely anything.

I've tried the built-in parsers (although I knew I'd probably have to write my own), I've written my own error parser (which I've then checked to see if it works), I've even tried adding new rules to the existing parsers, without any luck. Not even this regex seems to work: `(.*)`.

I've also tried using the *RegEx Error Parser* from iSystem; I've seen others who managed to successfully get it to work, but still nothing happened.

Has anyone had any luck in getting the error parser to correctly interpret the console output? I'm using the *Helios Service Release 2* of the Eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [the solution](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=206215&start=0&S=641b644614afdc7a7d65d3ed74bc4e04) after cross-posting my question on the Eclipse CDT forum:

**The error parsers only work for the built-in build tools**, so leave the builders as they are. Then, go to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build`, deselect the *Use default build command* and add your own batch file. Do the same thing in the `Behaviour` tab for the *Build on resource save (Auto build)* and the *Build (Incremental build)* options.

Afterwards, go to the `Error Parsers` tab in `C/C++ Build\Settings` and add your own error parser with the rules you want.

Answer (score 1):

The following changes fix problem for me:

1. Change Compiler pattern in to: .*((g?cc)|([gc]++)|(clang))
2. Add tobuild target “VERBOSE=1” (because I am using cmake)
3. Add –std=C++17 to Build-in Compiler settings
4. Check the "Index source and header files opened in editor" in indexer

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]